# Word problem with 3 variable(might contain a parametric solution).

Tags: systems-of-equations, word-problem

This is the question:

At The Crispy Critter’s Head Shop and Patchouli Emporium along with their dried up weeds, sunﬂower seeds and astrological postcards they sell an herbal tea blend. By weight, Type I herbal tea is $30\%$ peppermint, $40\%$ rose hips and $30\%$ chamomile, Type II has percents $40\%$, $20\%$ and $40\%$, respectively, and Type III has percents $35\%$, $30\%$ and $35\%$, respectively. How much of each Type of tea is needed to make $2$ pounds of a new blend of tea that is equal parts peppermint, rose hips and chamomile?

So the variables are the mass of each type of tea; type I's mass$=x$, type II's mass$=y$, type III's mass$=z$. Since we're about to make a blend of tea that's $2$ pounds in mass, then

$$x+y+z=2$$

Neat. But I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how to make use of that last part:"$2$ pounds of a new blend of tea that is equal parts peppermint, rose hips and chamomile". I know this means that our new blend of tea's composition will have equal parts but how do I make use of this?

With Ross Milikan's answer, this is what I can gather so far from my visual illustration. [image: What I understand so far]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new type IV tea has equal parts of each, so $\frac 23$ pound of each component.  If you use $x$ pounds of type I tea, you get $0.3x$ pounds of peppermint.  You can write three equations similar to the one you did, one for each component.  Then solve the three equations.

Comment: What do you mean by "If you use x pounds of type I tea, you get 0.3x pounds of peppermint."? I don't get it.

Comment: You are told that type I is $30\%$ peppermint by weight.  If you take a 1 pound scoop of the tea you get $0.3$ pounds of peppermint, $0.4$ pounds of rose hips and ....

Comment: What? Wait a second, are you saying that a "pound" of a type of tea comprise the stated percentage of components?

Comment: Any amount of the tea is composed by weight of the stated percentages of components.  That is why you are given the information.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that.

Comment: So we know that the sum of the 3 types of tea will be 2 pounds. And the composition of that tea that has mass of 2 pounds will have equal parts of components. I'm terribly sorry for being terribly inept at this but I truly have no idea how to proceed with this. The answer you gave is useful, it had changed my initial perception about the problem but I don't know how to proceed. I'm truly sorry for being rude, but can you provide the solution with step by step commentary?

Comment: Since you are making two pounds of mix with equal amounts of the three, you need $\frac 23$ pound of each component.  You can write an equation for the peppermint, which is $0.3x+0.4y+0.35z=\frac 23$.  This says the total amount of peppermint is the sum of that which came from each component in the blend.  You can write two similar equations for the other two components and have three equations in three unknowns.  Your $x+y+z=2$ will be the sum of the three equations, so does not add any information.